# Does an AMP url retain the query parameters?

Tags: php, seo, amp-html

I've seen this question asked before but a straight answer is hard to find. I've heard both sides of the story from reliable sources. Documentation is limited but I did find this article from Google.

https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#query-parameter-example

TLDR:

> Query parameter example
>   The AMP Cache URL format can also include parameters in the query string. The following is an HTTPS example with parameters: https://example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/example.com/g?value=Hello%20World

Can I use, say `$_GET['utm_source']` in PHP on a page I want cached with AMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the AMP cache supports query parameters. Here is an example:

https://ampbyexample-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/ampbyexample.com/g?value=Hello%20Alice
https://ampbyexample-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/ampbyexample.com/g?value=Hello%20Bob

Both links point to the same page, but render different content based on the query param. The AMP Cache mirrors this behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Would you be able to take a look at my question here as well? It's a very simple question that I've had a very hard time finding an answer to. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483723/internal-links-on-amp-pages