# Internal links on AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

Many topics on this but can't find a straight answer. How do I hard-code an internal link on my fully AMP validated website?

Relative links seem to be converted to absolute.
Do I have to link directly to the www.google.com/amp/s/ url?

**UPDATE:** I tried that, and it just redirects to my canonical link. Are we simply not supposed to use internal links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, AMP-to-AMP linking is not supported inside the Google AMP Viewer. Theoretically, it's possible to link to the version on the AMP cache (using the [AMP Cache URL scheme](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/guides/using_the_google_amp_cache/#amp-cache-url-format) `https://example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/example.com`).

However, the idiomatic way to use AMP would be to link back to the canonical version (or AMP version) on your own origin.